# Default lightweight non-server database for Windows Phone applications

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-phone-8

What is the default lightweight non-server database for Windows Phone applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually a few you could try,

By default you can use [WP7 Isolated Storage](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage--intro-to-isolated-storage)

Others are,

[Sterling](http://sterling.codeplex.com/)

[SQLite](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2010/03/sqlite-for-wp-7-series-proof-of-concept.html)